# MissingMethodException on NotifyPropertyChanged in local database app for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, inotifypropertychanged, missingmethodexception

I have been following the MSDN tutorial as a reference while making an MVC app for Winows Phone 7.1:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405(v=vs.92).aspx

In my app, I have an object in a table that implements the INotifyPropertyChanging and INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces implemented and a property like this:

```cs
private DateTime lastViewDate;
[Column]
public DateTime LastViewDate
{
    get { return lastViewDate; }
    set
    {
       if (lastViewDate != value)
       {
           NotifyPropertyChanging("LastViewDate");
           lastViewDate = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("LastViewDate");
       }
    }
}
```

When the LastViewDate property gets changed, a MissingMethodException gets thrown when NotifyPropertyChanging gets called even though the property is obviously there.  So what am I doing wrong?
(I'm a noob at wp7 programming so it might be obvious, just not to me)

EDIT: more info

Here is the interface method with some added calls to examine the methods:

```cs
    // Used to notify that a property is about to change
    private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        var type = this.GetType();
        var method = type.GetMethod(propertyName); // null
        var getMethod = type.GetMethod("get_" + propertyName); // works
        var setMethod = type.GetMethod("set_" + propertyName); // works
        var methods = type.GetMethods(); // set_LastViewDate is in the method list
        //
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Changing the call to NotifyPropertyChanging("set_LastViewDate"); still gives the same exception. (and 'method' gets null in the debug type checking)

EDIT:

Stack trace:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
Message=MissingMethodException
StackTrace:
   at System.Activator.InternalCreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at System.Data.Linq.WorkAround.ActivationHelper.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.StandardTrackedObject.CreateDataCopy(Object instance)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.StandardTrackedObject.StartTracking()
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.OnPropertyChanging(Object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs args)
   at WindowsPhonePlaces.Photo.NotifyPropertyChanging(String propertyName)
   at WindowsPhonePlaces.Photo.set_LastViewDate(DateTime value)
   at WindowsPhonePlaces.Photo.ResetViewDate()
   at WindowsPhonePlaces.PhotoViewerPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated(Object content, Uri uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean isNavigationInitiator, PhoneApplicationPage existingContentPage, PhoneApplicationPage newContentPage)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(DependencyObject content, NavigationMode mode)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginLoad>b__0(Object args)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

Comment: What are you trying do with reflection in the `NotifyPropertyChanging` method?

Comment: There is something else going on with the code; everything you've posted will work. Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I was trying to show that when I check out the problem via debugging, I  can see the method that it claims is missing via reflection (my 'methods' variable has the getter and setter for 'LastViewDate').  I am assuming that the framework subscribes to my PropertyChanging event and then crashes when it tries to use reflection to access the property.  (for some reason, the framework can't see the property like i can and crashes--that's why I'm confused...)

Comment: I have a suspicion this is related to `System.Data.Linq`. By chance does your class have an empty constructor? i.e., `public YourClass(){}` as opposed to `public YourClass(SomeType someType){}`. If not, then add an empty constructor and see if that resolves the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting the solution as a separate answer here to make it clear:

The problem was that I made the constructor private and used a static method to create my db objects.  This doesn't work with LINQ--you need a parameterless, public constructor.

Thanks to @Metro Smurf and @Rajeev Nair for figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is `PropertyChanging` declared public? If not, it should be set as public.

Comment: yes:    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

Comment: can you post the entire exception message?

Comment: See @Metro Smurf's comment. Add an empty constructor, and it should work.